# How to open a .exe window for CPP files in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: c++, c++14, sublimetext3

The run tool in Codeblocks offers to run the code interactively by opening a [.exe window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDvho.png) for CPP files. But to run the code in Sublime I had to open a .txt file that included the input data beforehand. Is there any way I can open a .exe window in Sublime like in Codeblocks?

Comment: Are you asking if there's a way to have a command terminal running inside Sublime?

Comment: @Clearer Yes, that's what I meant.